# wrong oldValue and newValue in valueChangeListener when using it together with a validator in a JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, validation, valuechangelistener

I am using a vlaidator and a valuechangeListener in a h:inputText field like this.

```
<h:inputText id="quantityInput" required="true"
validator="#{CartController.validateQuantity}"
value="#{cartLine.quantity}" size="6" maxlength="15"
styleClass="numeric"
onchange='updateAndSubmit("#{CartController.rowIndex +1}", "tabs_root:updatedRow")'
onkeyup='checkEnter(event,"#{CartController.rowIndex +1}", "tabs_root:updatedRow")'
style="margin-right:0.4em"
tabindex="#{CartController.tabIndex}"
valueChangeListener="#{CartController.quantityListener}">
<rd:convertNumber
    maxFractionDigits="#{CartController.noOfQuantityDecimals}"
    minFractionDigits="#{CartController.noOfQuantityDecimals}" />
</h:inputText>
```

I am getting the same oldValue and newvalue in my valuechangeListener when I am changing the inputText box. This problem is disappear when I am removing the validator, I am getting the right oldValue and new value in valuechangeListener when I am removing the validator.

What is going on here, do you have any idea?

and here is the validator method

```
    public void validateQuantity(FacesContext facesContext,
        UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException,
        Exception {

    try {
        if (isCurrentRowItem()) {
            int quantityValidationResult = quantityControl(value,
                    getCurrentGoods());
            if (quantityValidationResult != QUANTITY_OK) {

                setViewErrorColumn(true);
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage();
                if (quantityValidationResult == QUANTITY_TO_LOW) {
                    String felTextMiQuant = Text.get(
                            TextProperties.ANGIVENKVANTITETMINDREBESTKVANT,
                            getApUserData().getUser().getCultureSetting());
                    msg.setSummary(felTextMiQuant + " " + minQuantity);
                    getActiveCartAndTemplateTab().getErrorList().put(
                            new Integer(getRowIndex()), msg.getDetail());
                } else {
                    String felTextMuQuant = Text
                            .get(TextProperties.ANGIVENKVANTITETEJTILLATENMULTIPEL,
                                    getApUserData().getUser()
                                            .getCultureSetting());
                    msg.setSummary(felTextMuQuant + " " + multipleQuantity);
                    getActiveCartAndTemplateTab().getErrorList().put(
                            new Integer(getRowIndex()), msg.getDetail());
                }
                // Activate the previous tab, the one containing the errors,
                // in case the user tries to activate another
                if (cartAndTemplateController != null)
                    cartAndTemplateController
                            .setActiveTab(cartAndTemplateController
                                    .getActiveTab());
                throw new ValidatorException(msg);
            } else {

                // if we don't set here it will be impossible to correct more then one error
                double valueAsDouble;
                Line line = (Line) getCartEntity()
                        .getLines(getApUserData()).get(validatorCounter);

                if (value instanceof Long) {
                    valueAsDouble = ((Long) value).doubleValue();
                }

                else if (value instanceof String){
                    valueAsDouble = Double.parseDouble((String) value);
                }

                else {
                    valueAsDouble = (Double) value;
                }
                    line.setQuantity(getApUserData(), valueAsDouble);
            }
            validatorCounter++;
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the validator code? Because if the validator is run before the changes and it isn't validated then it will return back to the old values.

Comment: And are you sure the stuff you enter in the inputtext is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maneged to solve the problem :), here is the story:

actually before reaching valueChangeListener, target component still have its oldValue. 
after running the valueChangeListener , component's value will be change to newly entered value.

Since validator is running before valueChangeListener , any changes in the component's value in the validator method will affected the oldValue in the Listener method.

In my validator I am setting the component's value with newly entered value ( from  "Object value" argument of the validator class), so it cause to get the same oldvalue and newValue in the Listener.